# Obj C - Voice Over reorders when apply affineTransform on view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiaccessibility

I'm presenting an `ViewController` with `subviews`(`UILabel`, `Button`) and everything works fine. When I do accessibility testing it reads the `first element` correctly.

```
MyViewController *alert = [MyUtility errorWithStatusTitle:@"MY APP" message:@"Error"];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:^{ }];
```

But when I apply the `affineTransform`, my view gets rotated and the voice over reads the `last element` in the `subview` instead of the first one(I know this is the way it works) but, How can I make it read the first one.?

```
alert.view.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

Comment: Would you mind showing the entire code in a kind of github to take a look at the context in order to provide an accurate answer, please?

Comment: Usually, when you deal with layers, VoiceOver doesn't work as it should and UIAccessibilityElement is admittedly used as explained in the example of this detailed WWDC video ⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-16202.html

Comment: Thank you for your comments!! I got it fixed by using accessibilityElements property.